# Matching ObjectId to String for $graphLookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to run a `$graphLookup` like demonstrated in print bellow:

[image: $graphLookup sample]

The objective is to, given a specific record (commented `$match` there), retrieve it's full "path" throught `immediateAncestors` property. As you can see, it's not happening.

I introduced `$convert` here to deal with `_id` from collection as `string`, believing it could be possible to "match" with `_id` from `immediateAncestors` records list (which is a `string`).

So, I did run another test with different data (no `ObjectId`s involved):

```
db.nodos.insert({"id":5,"name":"cinco","children":[{"id":4}]})
db.nodos.insert({"id":4,"name":"quatro","ancestors":[{"id":5}],"children":[{"id":3}]})
db.nodos.insert({"id":6,"name":"seis","children":[{"id":3}]})
db.nodos.insert({"id":1,"name":"um","children":[{"id":2}]})
db.nodos.insert({"id":2,"name":"dois","ancestors":[{"id":1}],"children":[{"id":3}]})
db.nodos.insert({"id":3,"name":"três","ancestors":[{"id":2},{"id":4},{"id":6}]})
db.nodos.insert({"id":7,"name":"sete","children":[{"id":5}]})
```

And the query:

```
db.nodos.aggregate( [
  { $match: { "id": 3 } },
  { $graphLookup: {
      from: "nodos",
      startWith: "$ancestors.id",
      connectFromField: "ancestors.id",
      connectToField: "id",
      as: "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING"
    }
  },
  { $project: {
      "name": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING": "$ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING.id"
    }
  }
] )
```

...which outputs what I was expecting (the five records directly and indirectly connected to the one with `id` 3):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afe270fb4719112b613f1b4"),
    "id" : 3.0,
    "name" : "três",
    "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING" : [ 
        1.0, 
        4.0, 
        6.0, 
        5.0, 
        2.0
    ]
}
```

The question is: there is a way to achieve the objetive I mentioned in the beginning?

I'm running Mongo 3.7.9 (from official Docker)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not the way you seem to think it would. The problem here would appear to be that the `"from"` in `$graphLookup` is getting data from the "collection" and not the `$project` on successive recursions. You could try a "view" which does the projection and use that as the "from" source. Also you probably just want the aliased `$toString` or `$toObjectId` in this context, since there's no practical purpose for the `onError` in your context.

Comment: Keep in mind though that using `$convert` or it's aliases for this specific purpose is really a "band aid" and not a practical solution. The "real solution" is to make sure the data which "looks like an ObjectId" is actually of an `ObjectId` type in ALL places where you record it. This kind of "brute force" was never the intention of the casting conversions being introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the considerations Neil. Do you think that storing a true `ObjectId` there will make things better? If it happens that I could manage that, will the query works, without `$project` and `$convert`?

Comment: Sorry, been away. Your "screenshot" does not really help here. It would be better to discover the JSON view of the data and paste some of that into the question instead. My general opinion is that the "brute force" you are trying to do is not the correct approach, and instead the types should be converted in the data so that that actually match without coercion. But putting some clear data in the post we can use with copy/paste makes that easier to explain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are currently using a development version of MongoDB which has some features enabled expected to be released with MongoDB 4.0 as an official release. Note that some features may be subject to change before the final release, so production code should be aware of this before you commit to it.

## Why $convert fails here

Probably the best way to explain this is to look at your altered sample but replacing with [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) values for `_id` and "strings" for those under the the arrays:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e272"),
   "name" : "cinco",
   "children" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e273" } ]
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e273"),
  "name" : "quatro",
  "ancestors" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e272" } ],
  "children" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e277" } ]
},
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e274"),
  "name" : "seis",
  "children" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e277" } ]
},
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e275"),
  "name" : "um",
  "children" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e276" } ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e276"),
  "name" : "dois",
  "ancestors" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e275" } ],
  "children" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e277" } ]
},
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e277"),
  "name" : "três",
  "ancestors" : [
    { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e273" },
    { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e274" },
    { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e276" }
  ]
},
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5764419503c46544e278"),
  "name" : "sete",
  "children" : [ { "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e272" } ]
}
```

That should give a general simulation of what you were trying to work with.

What you attempted was to convert the `_id` value into a "string" via [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) before entering the [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) stage. The reason this fails is whilst you did an initial [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) "within" this pipeline, the problem is that the source for [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) in the `"from"` option is still the unaltered collection and therefore you don't get the correct details on the subsequent "lookup" iterations.

```
db.strcoll.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "três" } },
  { "$addFields": {
    "_id": { "$toString": "$_id" }
  }},
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "strcoll",
    "startWith": "$ancestors._id",
    "connectFromField": "ancestors._id",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING": "$ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING._id"
  }}
])
```

Does not match on the "lookup" therefore:

```
{
        "_id" : "5afe5763419503c46544e277",
        "name" : "três",
        "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING" : [ ]
}
```

## "Patching" the problem

However that is the core problem and not a failing of [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) or it's aliases itself. In order to make this actually work we can instead create a ["view"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) which presents itself as a collection for the sake of input.

I'll do this the other way around and convert the "strings" to [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) via [`$toObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/):

```
db.createView("idview","strcoll",[
  { "$addFields": {
    "ancestors": {
      "$ifNull": [ 
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$ancestors",
          "in": { "_id": { "$toObjectId": "$$this._id" } }
        }},
        "$$REMOVE"
      ]
    },
    "children": {
      "$ifNull": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$children",
          "in": { "_id": { "$toObjectId": "$$this._id" } }
        }},
        "$$REMOVE"
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Using the ["view"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) however means that the data is consistently seen with the values converted. So the following aggregation using the view:

```
db.idview.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "três" } },
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "idview",
    "startWith": "$ancestors._id",
    "connectFromField": "ancestors._id",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING": "$ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING._id"
  }}
])
```

Returns the expected output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e277"),
    "name" : "três",
    "ANCESTORS_FROM_BEGINNING" : [
        ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e275"),
        ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e273"),
        ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e274"),
        ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e276"),
        ObjectId("5afe5763419503c46544e272")
    ]
}
```

## Fixing the problem

With all of that said, the real issue here is that you have some data which "looks like" an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) value and is in fact valid as an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), however it has been recorded as a "string". The basic issue to everything working as it should is that the two "types" are not the same and this results in an equality mismatch as the "joins" are attempted.

So the real fix is still the same as it always has been, which is to instead go through the data and fix it so that the "strings" are actually also [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) values. These will then match the `_id` keys which they are meant to refer to, and you are saving a considerable amount of storage space since an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) takes up a lot less space to store than it's string representation in hexadecimal characters.

Using MongoDB 4.0 methods, you *"could"* actually use the [`"$toObjectId"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) in order to write a new collection, just in much the same matter that we created the "view" earlier:

```
db.strcoll.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "ancestors": {
      "$ifNull": [ 
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$ancestors",
          "in": { "_id": { "$toObjectId": "$$this._id" } }
        }},
        "$$REMOVE"
      ]
    },
    "children": {
      "$ifNull": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$children",
          "in": { "_id": { "$toObjectId": "$$this._id" } }
        }},
        "$$REMOVE"
      ]
    }
  }}
  { "$out": "fixedcol" }
])
```

Or of course where you "need" to keep the same collection, then the traditional "loop and update" remains the same as what has always been required:

```
var updates = [];

db.strcoll.find().forEach(doc => {
  var update = { '$set': {} };

  if ( doc.hasOwnProperty('children') )
    update.$set.children = doc.children.map(e => ({ _id: new ObjectId(e._id) }));
  if ( doc.hasOwnProperty('ancestors') )
    update.$set.ancestors = doc.ancestors.map(e => ({ _id: new ObjectId(e._id) }));

  updates.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      update
    }
  });

  if ( updates.length > 1000 ) {
    db.strcoll.bulkWrite(updates);
    updates = [];
  }

})

if ( updates.length > 0 ) {
  db.strcoll.bulkWrite(updates);
  updates = [];
}
```

Which is actually a bit of a "sledgehammer" due to actually overwriting the entire array in a single go. Not a great idea for a production environment, but enough as a demonstration for the purposes of this exercise.

## Conclusion

So whilst MongoDB 4.0 will add these "casting" features which can indeed be very useful, their actual intent is not really for cases such as this. They are in fact much more useful as demonstrated in the "conversion" to a new collection using an aggregation pipeline than most other possible uses.

Whilst we *"can"* create a "view" which transforms the data types to enable things like [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to work where the actual collection data differs, this really is only a *"band-aid"* on the real problem as the data types really should not differ, and should in fact be permanently converted.

Using a "view" actually means that the aggregation pipeline for construction needs to effectively run **every** time the "collection" ( actually a "view" ) is accessed, which creates a real overhead.

Avoiding overhead is usually a design goal, therefore correcting such data storage mistakes is imperative to getting real performance out of your application, rather than just working with "brute force" that will only slow things down.

---

A much safer "conversion" script which applied "matched" updates to each array element. The code here requires NodeJS v10.x and a latest release MongoDB node driver 3.1.x:

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID: ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const EJSON = require('mongodb-extended-json');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/';

const log = data => console.log(EJSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
    let db = client.db('test');
    let coll = db.collection('strcoll');

    let fields = ["ancestors", "children"];

    let cursor = coll.find({
      $or: fields.map(f => ({ [`${f}._id`]: { "$type": "string" } }))
    }).project(fields.reduce((o,f) => ({ ...o, [f]: 1 }),{}));

    let batch = [];

    for await ( let { _id, ...doc } of cursor ) {

      let $set = {};
      let arrayFilters = [];

      for ( const f of fields ) {
        if ( doc.hasOwnProperty(f) ) {
          $set = { ...$set,
            ...doc[f].reduce((o,{ _id },i) =>
              ({ ...o, [`${f}.$[${f.substr(0,1)}${i}]._id`]: ObjectId(_id) }),
              {})
          };

          arrayFilters = [ ...arrayFilters,
            ...doc[f].map(({ _id },i) =>
              ({ [`${f.substr(0,1)}${i}._id`]: _id }))
          ];
        }
      }

      if (arrayFilters.length > 0)
        batch = [ ...batch,
          { updateOne: { filter: { _id }, update: { $set }, arrayFilters } }
        ];

      if ( batch.length > 1000 ) {
        let result = await coll.bulkWrite(batch);
        batch = [];
      }

    }

    if ( batch.length > 0 ) {
      log({ batch });
      let result = await coll.bulkWrite(batch);
      log({ result });
    }

    await client.close();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

Produces and executes bulk operations like these for the seven documents:

```
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e272"
      }
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "children.$[c0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e273"
        }
      }
    },
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "c0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e273"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e273"
      }
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "ancestors.$[a0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e272"
        },
        "children.$[c0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e277"
        }
      }
    },
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "a0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e272"
      },
      {
        "c0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e277"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e274"
      }
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "children.$[c0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e277"
        }
      }
    },
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "c0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e277"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e275"
      }
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "children.$[c0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e276"
        }
      }
    },
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "c0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e276"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e276"
      }
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "ancestors.$[a0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e275"
        },
        "children.$[c0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e277"
        }
      }
    },
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "a0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e275"
      },
      {
        "c0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e277"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e277"
      }
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "ancestors.$[a0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e273"
        },
        "ancestors.$[a1]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e274"
        },
        "ancestors.$[a2]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e276"
        }
      }
    },
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "a0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e273"
      },
      {
        "a1._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e274"
      },
      {
        "a2._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e276"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afe5764419503c46544e278"
      }
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": {
        "children.$[c0]._id": {
          "$oid": "5afe5763419503c46544e272"
        }
      }
    },
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "c0._id": "5afe5763419503c46544e272"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! I'll stay with performance and  go with "clean" fields from the beginning 

Comment: @Cesar It was worth writing because you won't be the last to ask it. People already ask it now who are yet not aware that these "conversion" functions are coming. Once it hits production I would expect the number of people attempting it to only increase. So "thanks for asking" I guess.