# Mongoose aggregate pipeline not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use the Mongoose aggregate pipeline to query my `User` collection and `Company` collection simultaneously. 
Specifically, I am trying to return all `users` and return the user's associated `companyName`. Each user has a `companyId` attribute
that maps to a `company` `_id` field. Here are my sample `user` and `company` documents:

```
User:
{
    _id: ObjectId("5b12ef5ba07ce1f8b212f07b"),
    companyId: "12345"
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe",
}

Company:

{
    _id: ObjectId("12345"),
    companyName: "UPS"
}
```

Here is my query code:

```
User.aggregate([{
    $match: {}
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            localField: "companyId",
            from: "company",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "companyInfo"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$companyInfo"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            first: 1,
            last: 1,
            "companyInfo.companyName": 1,
        }
    }
], (err, users) => {
    console.log(users) // returns []
});
```

I THINK the reason is the `companyId` is stored as a string in my `User` collection, but it is an `objectId` in the `company` collection.
Can anyone confirm? And if it is the issue, I'm not sure how to resolve it... Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is indeed the different types. As noted on the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402500/matching-objectid-to-string-for-graphlookup) the solution is to "fix your data" and not using new methods to cast at runtime as has been suggested. That answer actually shows exactly why runtime casting is not the answer and why you really need to correct your data instead. It also shows examples of how to go about converting your data in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct.

When doing `$lookup`, local field and remote field must be of the same type.

There are no way to do a converter when lookup, afaik.

This is the related issue:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781

The version 3.7.3 has it implemented

For now you might want to change your data type